Boot takes very long with a bunch of usb errors
I have a computer with Ubuntu Mate freshly installed, and the boot takes several minutes, and from the kernel boot log I see that it seems to be waiting on some USB devices.
I see many seconds wasted by errors of the form
[t]     usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[t+16s] new full speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[t+16s] usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[t+32s] usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[t+46s] usb5-port2 attempt power cycle
[t+46s] new full speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[t+51s] xhci_hcd 000:0e:00.3: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[t+57s] xhci_hcd 000:0e:00.3: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[t+57s] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 4, error -62
[t+57s] usb 5-2: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command
… a few more repeats …
[t+68s] usb usb5-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

so I am spending more than a minute waiting and it seems to be about 1 usb port. I know that one of my ports on the computer doesn't work, but so far no other OS (windows or the previous elementaryOS install) had any problems.
Can I somehow disable this port or change the timeouts so the boot completes faster?

just FYI, this is exactly the error you get when you attach a device electrically to a USB port, but forget to make the device react to anything (e.g., you connect a USB-capable microcontroller, but then don't write firmware that actually does USB). I guess you've done this before, but make sure you try booting with as many USB devices unplugged as you can.
